# Algorithm - Group Geographic Points in Rows

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

I have a set of x,y coordinates (in meters) for an orchard.  I'm trying to automatically group rows and to number the trees inside the groups (rows) from top to bottom (based on a definition of what top and bottom are). Unfortunately, I have not been able to come up with a solution.  See below for a picture as well as a link to a dataset.

An example of a number for a tree would be:

5-1

5-2

where 5 is the row number and 1 and 2 are the number of the tree inside the row.

The distance between trees in a row is about 6 meters, and between the rows about 12 meters. Thus a row can be defined where the neighboring trees are less than 7 meters away using Euclidean distance.  Organizing the data by y coordinates does not work as the rows are not straight lines.

To make things more complicated, the rows need to be in order from either left to right or right to left.

Is there an existing algorithm that I can use?  If not, what can I do to make this work?  Some direction will be appreciated!

Data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csLM4IpP3tMF0fqQkql6gIANHngX9A3c/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You are looking for a [line fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_fitting) algorithm. First determine which points are on the same line and which not by applying such a fitting algorithm. Then sort the points of a line by the line direction and give them numbers.

Comment: I have thought of that, but I first need a line in order to compare the points with.  To get the line, I need a list of ordered points.  Get the issue here?

Comment: If the distance between trees can be 6 meters, you can have a tree at (0, 0), another at (0, 6), another at (0, 12)... From the point of view of (0, 6) both (0, 0) and (0, 12) are on same row, yet from (0, 0) only (0, 6) is. Not sure how would you handle that. Also don´t understand the picture, are the points the trees? Why are some green and some red?

Comment: Yes the points are the trees.  It is the snapshot from plotting the points on a GIS system.  There are about 6500 trees.  The color is just the type of tree.  What is important is the x,y of the point (tree).  

The coordinates are taken from the field, so I cannot create my own layout (if I understand correctly what you are proposing)

Comment: I mean I don´t see a way to know which trees lie on a row with your definition

Comment: @ceds 1. Pick a point. 2. Search for the closest neighbour of the first point. If their distance is < rowDistance you have probably two points of a line. If not, start at 1. with another point. 3. Search for the closest neighbour of the second point and check if their distance is < rowDistance. If not ... 4. Now you have probably three points of a line. Determine the line fitting through these 3 points. 5. Now measure the distance of all remaining points to this line and choose all points that are close enough. 6. Double check if those points are close enough to a line by doing a line fit

Comment: with all points from step 1, 2, 3 and  5. 7. If ok remove those points from the initial list of all points. 8. Repeat to find the next lines until all points are assigned to lines.

Comment: That might actually work.  I'll try to implement it and post the solution if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.  See below for my solution.  It is very messy, but I'm sure the idea will come through:

[image]

```
public class Group
{
    public int group;
    public int row;
    public double highestRelDistance;

    public Group(int _group)
    {
        group = _group;
    }

}

public class Tree
{
    public string name;
    public Group group = new Group(0);
    public int orderInGroup;
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public string type;
    public double relDistance;
}



public static void FitTreesToLine(List<Tree> treesList, out double m, out double c)
{
    double[] xdata = treesList.Select(x => x.x).ToArray();
    double[] ydata = treesList.Select(x => x.y).ToArray();

    Tuple<double, double> p = Fit.Line(xdata, ydata);
    double a = p.Item1; // == 10; intercept
    double b = p.Item2; // == 0.5; slope

    m = b;
    c = a;
}

public static double FindDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(double m, double c, double point_x, double point_y )
{

    double line_start_x = point_x * 0.5;
    double line_start_y = m * line_start_x + c;

    double line_end_x = point_x * 1.5;
    double line_end_y = m * line_end_x + c;

    double distance = Math.Abs((line_end_x - line_start_x) * (line_start_y - point_y) - (line_start_x - point_x) * (line_end_y - line_start_y)) /
            Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(line_end_x - line_start_x, 2) + Math.Pow(line_end_y - line_start_y, 2));

    return (distance);

}

 public static void DoCalculations(List<Tree> treeList)
 {

    //Calculate groups
    Group curGroup = new Group(1);
    groupList.Add(curGroup);

    int searchFailures = 0;

    treeGrouping:

    List<Tree> noGroupList = treeList.Where(x => x.group.group == 0).ToList();
    List<Tree> closeTreeList = new List<Tree>();

    if (noGroupList.Count() >= 3 && searchFailures < 1000)
    {

        var refTree = noGroupList[0];
        closeTreeList.Add(refTree);
        for (int i = 1; i < noGroupList.Count(); i++)
        {

            double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(refTree.x - noGroupList[i].x, 2) + Math.Pow(refTree.y - noGroupList[i].y, 2));

            if (distance <= 7)
            {
                closeTreeList.Add(noGroupList[i]);

                if (closeTreeList.Count() == 2)
                {
                    //Fit linear curve
                    double m = 0;
                    double c = 0;
                    FitTreesToLine(closeTreeList, out m, out c);

                    //Find all points that is close to the line in original tree list
                    for (int j = 0; j < noGroupList.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        double distanceFromLine = FindDistanceBetweenPointAndLine(m, c, noGroupList[j].x, noGroupList[j].y);

                        if (distanceFromLine <= 8)
                        {
                            noGroupList[j].group = curGroup;
                        }
                    }

                    //Iterate current group
                    curGroup = new Group(curGroup.group + 1);
                    groupList.Add(curGroup);

                    goto treeGrouping;

                }
            }
        }

        refTree.group.group = 9999999;

        //curGroup = new Group(curGroup.group + 1);
        //groupList.Add(curGroup);

        searchFailures++;
        goto treeGrouping;

    }

    //Order trees within their groups
    foreach (var group in groupList)
    {
        var groupTreeList = treeList.Where(x => x.group == group).OrderBy(x => x.y).ToList();
        for (int i = 0;i < groupTreeList.Count();i++)
        {
            groupTreeList[i].orderInGroup = i + 1;
        }
    }

    //Get max group rel distance
    foreach (var group in groupList)
    {

        var items = treeList.Where(x => x.group == group);

        if (items.Count() > 0)
        {
            group.highestRelDistance = items.OrderBy(x=>x.orderInGroup).Last().x;
        }

    }

    //Order tree groups into rows
    groupList = groupList.OrderBy(x => x.highestRelDistance).ToList();
    for (int i = 0;i < groupList.Count();i++)
    {
        var items = treeList.Where(x => x.group == groupList[i]).ToList();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.group.row = i;
        }

    }

    //Generate tree names
    foreach (var tree in treeList)
    {
        tree.name = "(" + tree.group.row.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + "-" + tree.orderInGroup.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + ")";
    }

    //Order list
    treeList = treeList.OrderBy(x => x.group.row).ThenBy(x => x.orderInGroup).ToList();
```

}